# Java RestTemplate Returning Null Values when Extract Data

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I was having some problem when trying to extract data from JSON using RestTemplate. Here is the sample JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "position": "pos1",
            "firstName": "test",
            "lastName": "doe",
            "employeeId": "123",
            "email": [
                "test@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        "highlightings": [],
        "sortValues": []
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "position": "pos2",
            "firstName": "test2",
            "lastName": "john",
            "employeeId": "456",
            "email": [
                "test2@gmail.com"
            ]
        },
        "highlightings": [],
        "sortValues": []
    }
]
```

And my object class:

```
public class Employee {

    private Long employeeId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;
    private String position;
}
```

The part where I am using RestTemplate and tried to print out the returned data:

```
ResponseEntity<Employee[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(
            builder.build().encode().toUri(),
            HttpMethod.GET,
            requestEntity,
            Employee[].class
        );

        System.out.println(response.getBody());
        for(int i = 0; i < response.getBody().length; i++){
            System.out.println(response.getBody()[i].getEmployeeId());
            System.out.println(response.getBody()[i].getEmail());
        }
```

However, it keeps returning null for all the fields. I tested to return rest template as string it did managed to show the list of record. However, when I tried to return as array of objects it became null.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: try to use @JsonProperty("data") and @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true) on Employee

Comment: I get this syntax error when trying to put on top of Employee class: '@JsonProperty' not applicable to type. Changed it to @JsonRootname also getting null

Comment: ok than JsonProperty can only be used on properties. try to rename employee to Data

Comment: @sge Changed it already using the code above still returning null. but the number of returned objects is correct, just that all the fields are null

Comment: i would say you have to define a "Data" object inside employee that contains firstname and lastname and then it should work

Comment: @sge Sorry but what do you mean? Create the Employee class with the 5 fields + Data object? And what to put in the Data class?

Comment: something like this
public class Employee {
private Data data;

}

class Data{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

}

Comment: I see I see but just a quick check, is there anyway we can specify json property on class level? Like for example map the Employee to data property in JSON

Comment: There are a few possible ways you can map nested objects with Jackson. Check out [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-nested-values)

Comment: you could also try to use JsonRootName("data") on employee class. it might work without an other nested class